# Process Builder - Flows - Touch (Edit) Record AFTER It Is Saved/Committed

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, automation

Is it possible to write a Flow which literally says:

**When RECORD is created (and totally committed), touch it again**

Alternate way of looking at it:

**IF(  ISNEW() ) THEN { EDIT/SAVE }**

It's not *efficient*.  It's not even *appropriate* by many's standards.  It is **necessary** in this case.

I'm desperate for a workaround for (managed package) Rootstock control of various things.  My fear is that Flows may ONLY WORK within the Order of Execution during the record creation, versus a "once it's fully committed, touch it again" method.

---

**CLARIFICATION**:   By "commit", I'm referring to touching the record AFTER it has completed the Order Of Execution, after the last step (to my understanding, the "post-commit logic").  It could be BEFORE that last step as well (after the "commits all DML operations" step)

---

**MORE CLARIFICATION**:   An ACCOUNT is created; it causes (managed code) Apex to create a "CUSTOMER" record, and that record (during creation) gets a LOOKUP back to the ACCOUNT.

I need a LOOKUP from ACCOUNT to the "CUSTOMER" record as well.

I can't do it in Process Builder (minus a "timed" event) because ERROR happens.  If it were to happen AFTER the "CUSTOMER" is created, it would work fine.

When a "CUSTOMER" is created, I want to TOUCH (edit-save) that same "CUSTOMER" record AGAIN AUTOMATICALLY so it can THEN set the LOOKUP on it's related ACCOUNT back to it.

Another way of explaining:   When a 'CUSTOMER' record is created, I want to touch (edit-save) it immediately AFTER it is created.

CURRENT WORK AROUND is TIMED:  I tell Process Builder to "wait until 2 hours prior to Create Date" of the "CUSTOMER" record, and then make the relationship on the related Account.  This is a separate edit-save (touch) operation and works fine, BUT it takes 30-90 seconds for it to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do what you are looking for, but you *have* to set a field value. That being said, it should suffice to set a field to itself.

1. Criteria:

   - Formula - `ISNEW()`
2. Action:

   - Update Records (record which triggered the flow)
   - Pick a field to update, then use a formula for the value, which also specifies that field

It might make more sense to just use `Apex`, but it sounds like you want a declarative solution. Process Builder is as late as you could put such declarative functionality.

If you want your empty update to occur completely outside (after) the Execution Order, you will need asynchronous functionality, and that is *not possible without code*. Your basic structure would simply be:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectService
{
    public static Boolean shouldCallAsync()
    {
        return !system.isFuture() && !system.isBatch() &&
            Limits.getLimitFutureCalls() > Limits.getFutureCalls();
    }

    @future
    public static void emptyUpdateAsync(Set<Id> recordIds)
    {
        List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>();
        for (Id recordId : recordIds) records.add(new MyObject__c(Id=recordId));
        emptyUpdate(records);
    }
    public static void emptyUpdate(List<MyObject__c> records)
    {
        if (shouldCallAsync())
            emptyUpdateAsync(new Map<Id, SObject>(records).keySet());
        else
            update records;
    }
}
```

You can then call this method from your trigger/handler pattern of choice. There are a few pieces of the above that might belong in other portions of your code base (were you a developer), but this is a simplified version that you could run with.

Comment: Your solution unfortunately makes no sense to me.  I don't see how it happens AFTER the initial COMMIT has happened to the database.   Wouldn't what you propose simply happen "during" the OOE of the record being created?    As for Apex, I'm trying to stay out of direct Apex if possible.  I know it can happen that way.  :-/

Comment: You haven't really made clear *why* it needs to happen after a certain step in the Execution Order. Can you please edit your post to clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I thought "commit" was clear.   After the *last* step of the OOE.  I'll add that.

Comment: @AMM That still doesn't really clear up the *why*. I didn't vote down, but that may be why someone else felt compelled to do so.

Comment: I try NOT to put on a dev hat (since I rate myself a 3-4 out of 10 and do not WANT to dev [code] when possible).   I used "commit" since it seemed prevalent in the OOE 'documentation'. Sorry.  :-/

Comment: Just a clarification if anyone is reading now... "you will need asynchronous functionality, and that is not possible without code". This is now possible in Process Builder and Flow as of about Winter '20 (or maybe 1 release earlier). You can now do a Wait Time of 0 hours.